# PHP: If statement issue

Tags: php

The array `resAlloc` contains 10 columns and 5 rows. All entries are equal to 0. So, I expect the following IF statement be TRUE, but it's false for some reason... Why?

```
if ($resAlloc[$i][$j] != 'ts' && $resAlloc[$i][$j] != 't' && $resAlloc[$i][$j] != 'st') {
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!=` evaluates `0` as `false`. Use `!==` which is more *strict*.

Comment: How does that explain the problem? `0!='ts'` and `false!='ts'` should both evaluate to `true`, and so the if statement as a whole should be true.

Comment: Right, but I don't understand why any of the comparisons would evaluate to false just based on the fact that != treats `0` as `false`. ... Oh, this is an issue of order of operations, isn't it? The OP probably wanted the three `!=` comparisons to be evaluated before the `&&`  operations, and that's probably not what's happening.

Comment: There's a completely separate issue, which is that `0 != 'any string'` also evaluates to `false` (see my answer below).

Comment: I don't think you were downvoted. I upvoted you for a minute and then removed the upvote when I realized that I didn't understand your answer, and then I did comment. I'll upvote you again if one of us manages to straighten me out.

Comment: Sorry about the serial commenting; I should have added that the problem I mentioned actually would be addressed by your suggestion to use strict comparison. And they're kind of the same problem after all.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC anything equaling 0 with != will return FALSE.

Comment: That's not correct. `0!=1` returns `true` (thank heavens!). I think this is an issue with comparing strings to integers -- strings get cast to the integer zero, so the two end up being equal after all!

Comment: I said IIRC, wasn't sure exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're comparing a string and an integer, and PHP is "helpfully" casting the string to an integer -- the integer zero. `0!='ts'` evaluates as `false`, because the comparison it ends up doing after conversion is `0!=0`. You can prevent this by explicitly treating the contents of your array as a string:

```
strval($resAlloc[$i][$j]) != 'ts'
```

This will do the comparison `'0'!='ts'`, which correctly evaluates to `true`. If you pass strval() a string it returns it unchanged, so this should be safe to use regardless of what's in your array.

Alternately, as Samy Dindane said, you can just use !== which won't do any type conversion.